# withNavigation can only be used on a view hierarchy of a navigator React Native paper

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I used `React Native paper` [BottomNavigation](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/bottom-navigation.html).  Now i try to Go back button withNavigation in tab and i receive error

> Invariant Violation: withNavigation can only be used on a view hierarchy of a navigator. The wrapped component is unable to get access to navigation from props or context.

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, StatusBar, Button} from 'react-native'
import { Subheading, withTheme } from 'react-native-paper'
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
import styles from '../assets/css/Style';  

class HomePageView extends React.Component { 
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.container]}>
                <StatusBar hidden />
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Subheading>Home Screen</Subheading>
                </View>
                <Button
                    title="Back"
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.props.navigation.goBack();
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}


function HomeScreen({ theme }) {
    const { colors } = theme
    return (<HomePageView style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: colors.surface }]} />) 
} 


export default withNavigation(withTheme(HomeScreen));
```

Comment: Can you show where you define your navigator?

Comment: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/bottom-navigation.html
I use this navigation

Comment: You are using  ```react-native-paper``` and  ```withNavigation``` belongs to another library  ```react-navigation```

Comment: Thanks , I already change to `react-navigation`

Answer (score 1):

I think,

> You are using react-native-paper and withNavigation belongs to another
>   library react-navigation

,Thanks